# Set PlotLabel length

Tags: plotting

This is a small adjustment I am making to a nice presentation from Welwyn Hollis's CalcLabs, Mathematica, Singe Variable Calculus.

```
slopeExplorer[fn_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}] :=
 DynamicModule[{f},
      f[t_] = fn /. x -> t;
      Manipulate[
       Show[
        Plot[{f[x], f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)}, {x, xmin, xmax},
         PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Orange]},
         PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax},
         PlotLabel -> 
          Pane["Slope of tangent line = " <> 
            ToString[Round[f'[a], 0.01]]]],
        Plot[f'[x], {x, xmin - 0.01, a},
         PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]],
        Graphics[{
          Gray, Line[{{a, f[a]}, {a, f'[a]}}],
          Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{a, f[a]}],
          Blue, Point[{a, f'[a]}]
          }]
        ], {a, xmin, xmax}
       ]
      ]
    slopeExplorer[2 x^3 - 3 x^2 - 36 x, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -150, 150}]
```

I would like to make some adjustments to the PlotLabel I've added.

1. As I move the slider, I'd like the PlotLabel to note jump about changing length, etc.
2. I'd also like to add a line of space between the PlotLabel and the coordinate system.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
slopeExplorer[fn_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}] := 
 DynamicModule[{f}, f[t_] = fn /. x -> t;
  Manipulate[Show[Plot[{f[x], f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)}, {x, xmin, xmax},
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue], Directive[Orange]},
     PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax},
     PlotLabel -> 
      Pane["Slope of tangent line = " <> 
        ToString[PaddedForm[f'[a], {6, 2}]] <> "\n", 200]],
    Plot[f'[x], {x, xmin - 0.01, a},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]],
    Graphics[{Gray, Line[{{a, f[a]}, {a, f'[a]}}], Red, 
      PointSize[Medium], Point[{a, f[a]}], Blue, 
      Point[{a, f'[a]}]}]], {a, xmin, xmax}]]
slopeExplorer[2 x^3 - 3 x^2 - 36 x, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -150, 150}]
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Great answer. Thanks for the help. This will keep the students' eyes from blinking when they use this demonstration.

Comment: Try `slopeExplorer[(1 - x)/(2 + x), {x, -4, 3}, {y, -20, 20}]`. I think the title thinks it has an exact slope number until your start moving the slider. I found that this cures the problem: `PaddedForm[N[f'[a]], {6, 2}]]`. Recommend edit to your code.

Comment: Try this example: `slopeExplorer[Sqrt[x - 1], {x, 1.0001, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]`. What happens is the beginning part of the dashed derivative curve begins to disappear as the slider moves to the right. Turns out this fixed this problem: `Plot[f'[x], {x, xmin - 0.01, a},
 PlotRange -> All,`

Comment: Turns out my previous comment caused a problem. See: [Some time difficulty in a Manipulate program inside a DynamicModule](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103301/some-time-difficulty-in-a-manipulate-program-inside-a-dynamicmodule). So don't use PlotRange->All. The best version of this demonstration code that now exists is on [Some time difficulty in a Manipulate program inside a DynamicModule](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103301/some-time-difficulty-in-a-manipulate-program-inside-a-dynamicmodule). See Bob Hanlon's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may also wish to make use of [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

```
slopeExplorer[
   fn_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}] :=
  DynamicModule[{f, pta, ptb},
   f[t_] = fn /. x -> t;
   Manipulate[
    pta = {a, f[a]};
    ptb = {a, f'[a]};
    Show[
     Plot[{Tooltip[f[x]], Tooltip[f[a] + f'[a] (x - a)]},
      {x, xmin, xmax},
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange},
      PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax},
      PlotLabel -> Row[{
         "Slope of tangent line =",
         Style[
          ToString[
            NumberForm[Round[f'[a], 0.01], {5, 2},
             NumberSigns -> {"-", " "},
             NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}]] <> "\n",
          FontFamily -> "Courier", Bold]},
        Alignment -> {Center, Right}]],
     Plot[Tooltip[f'[x]], {x, xmin - 0.01, a},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]],
     Graphics[{Gray, Line[{pta, ptb}],
       Red, PointSize[Medium], Tooltip[Point[pta], pta],
       Blue, Tooltip[Point[ptb], ptb]}]],
    {{a, xmin, "x"}, xmin, xmax, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]];

slopeExplorer[2 x^3 - 3 x^2 - 36 x, {x, -5, 6}, {y, -150, 150}]
```

Comment: A definite essential addition. Students will also find this very helpful. Thanks for the tip.